# Material Ui components not behaving as expected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

This is my code, I am unable when I try and Click on the text fields nothing happens.

```
 class Contact extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
    <Wrapper >
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
        <header>

        <CommonBar />

        </header>
        <Banner>
         <h1> Contact Us </h1>
        </Banner>
        <PleaseFill> Let's do business together! Send us a Message.

        </PleaseFill>

        <Fields>

        <TextField
        floatingLabelText="Please enter your full name"
        hintText = "Full Name"
        fullWidth={true}
        type = "text"
         />
         <br/>
         <TextField
        floatingLabelText="Please enter your contact number"
        hintText = "Number"
        fullWidth={true}
        type = "number"

         />
         <br/>
         <TextField
        floatingLabelText="Please enter your email id"
        hintText = "Email Id"
        fullWidth={true}


         />
         <br/>
         <TextField
        floatingLabelText="Enter your message"
        hintText = "Message Body"
        multiLine={true}
        rows ={5}
        fullWidth={true}

         />
         <br/>
         <br/>
         <br/>
         <Button>
        <RaisedButton label="Send" primary={true} style = {{ width: '16rem', height: '3.25rem'}} labelStyle = {labelStyle} />
        </Button>


        </ Fields>
        </ MuiThemeProvider>
    </ Wrapper>
    );
 }
 }

 export default Contact;
```

I am using styled-components to style.

If you check out Contact_us component you will see my code. On the link below you can check my code.
Material-ui works fine in Homepage.js component. Please check my full code here.

https://github.com/SamkitS/showell/blob/master/src/components/Contact_Us.js
As you can see I have imported MuiThemeProvider, Raised Button, TextField etc.

Terminal does not show any bugs.
I am using create react app.
I have checked all the solutions offered on StackOverflow but nothing works.
Please help.

Expected resulted should be the way it is shown in the docs. https://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field

Comment: Can you format your code?